# Evitar la carga de entidades relacionada en EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-5.0

Tengo un problema con proyecto en blazor (wasm hospedada) con EF Core y net core 5.

Tengo las tablas (hay mas):
Profesores (id, email, nombre)
Matriculas (id, idProfesor, idAsignatura, idCurso,idAdlumno)
Cursos (id, idEtapa, nombre)

Lo que pretendo es obtener un listado en un webapi de los cursos que imparte un profesor:

```
// GET: api/Cursos
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Curso>>> GetCursos()
  {
  _context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  string email = "profesor@mail.com";

  Profesore profesor = _context.Profesores.Where(p => p.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
  List<Matricula> matriculas = _context.Matriculas.Include(i=>i.IdCursoNavigation).Where(p => p.IdProfesor == profesor.Id).ToList();
  List<Curso> lcurso = matriculas.Select(s => s.IdCursoNavigation).Distinct().ToList();
  return lcurso;
  }
```

Se que las consultas se pueden optimizar pero ahora mismo lo que quiero es solucionar el problema.
El problema que tengo es que en lcurso tengo la información de los cursos y de todas las entidades que están relacionadas, y yo solo quiero la información de los cursos, porque aunque la consulta se ejecuta correctamente obtengo un error de json:

> JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

Lo que debería ser un json de 10 líneas es uno de 200
Si en el startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

Soluciono el error, pero deja de funcionar el resto del proyecto porque no hay deserializa de forma automática.

`_context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` es no hace nada, carga los mismos datos.

Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Gracias

Comment: Por qué desactivaste Lazy Loading? Lazy loading va a cargar las entidades relacionadas cuando intentes acceder a una propiedad de navegación. Hace EXACTAMENTE lo que estás pidiendo en el título de tu pregunta. Además, con el `.Include()`, le estás diciendo EXPLÍCITAMENTE que cargue las entidades. Creo que quieres ir al norte caminando hacia el sur.

Comment: He probado con LazyLoading con true y con false con idéntico resultado. He probado a hacer las consultas por separado, sin los includes identico resultado. Si hago obtengo un listado de todos los cursos (_context.Curso.ToList()) no carga ningún dato adicional, en el momento en el que pongo una condición, ya carga todos los datos (ya sea con includes, con contains, con any, da igual)

Comment: He encontrado una solución un poco "chapuza" y es conseguir un listado de los id de los cursos con contexto y luego obtener los cursos son otro contexto, de esta forma no se cargan los datos relacionados

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que el Include esta armando un bucle infinito "his can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32", te recomiendo tener un DTO y antes de hacer un response transformalo a este

```
public class MatriculaDTO{
 ...
 public IdCursoNavigationDTO IdCursoNavigation{get;set;}
}
public class IdCursoNavigationDTO {
  ... //No deberia tener el List<MatriculaDTO> como propiedad
}
```

Ahora para hacer la transformación de recomiendo utilizar Mapster
https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster

Saludos

Comment: Esa solución es correcta para evitar los ciclos en el JSON pero no para evitar que se carguen más datos de la base de datos.